# Pushing to another user's remote repository without the use of pull requests

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-remote

I'm trying to make a github repository on which a group of 4 users can work on at the same time, without having to make a pull request for every push or making a fork every time a change is made.

However, when anyone who isn't the creator (me) adds the remote URL and tries to push to the master branch it denies access to the user, even though the user is added on the github page as a contributor.

To figure this out I told one of the users to fork the repo and add me as a contributor so that I could try pushing new changes, but I'm experiencing the same issue.

I did the following in Git Bash:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git
Cloning into 'AlaBonteKoe'...
remote: Counting objects: 3027, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 3027 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2955
Receiving objects: 100% (3027/3027), 37.23 MiB | 588.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (494/494), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ vim README.MD

(I make edits to the readme)

$ git commit -a -m "test remote commit"
[master 318b667] test remote commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/nebbii/AlaBonteKoe.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git (push)

$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git denied to nebbii.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git/':
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Is it possible to push changes to the repo as a listed contributor without having to create pull requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely is possible!

I would recommend using the SSH protocol to clone the repository. That way your are using you ssh keys to authenticate instead of http basic authentication.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git
```

See the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) on Github as well.

Comment: Strange, when I try to clone a repository via SSH key, i get the following:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the private ssh key corresponding to the public one in your Github settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git remote add origin github.com/nebbii/AlaBonteKoe.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git remote -v
origin  github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git (fetch)
origin  github.com/Diseasedfire/AlaBonteKoe.git (push)
```

When you look at the output of git remote -v you can see that there is already a remote called origin. So if you want to add the new remote URL you need to name the remote different.

```
git remote add FOO github.com/nebbii/AlaBonteKoe.git
```

Then you can push to the other repo. (git push FOO master) for pushing branch master to FOO

But to answer your main Question.
Just create a github repo add the others as contributers and let them clone your repo. Then very one of you 4 can create his own branch an work on that branch. Later if you need the code/stuff of the others just merge it into master or in the branch where you need the code.

For further reading; You could also use rebase if the branches are not shared or just look here: 
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow